# Does anyone know the model and year of this giant?

Tags: giant

I was wanting to know what year and model this giant is. Looking into buying and also wanted to know what size wheels I could fit on it was hoping to put bigger tires on. [image]

Comment: Somewhere between 1980 and 2020.

Comment: *"put bigger tires on it."* Do you mean *wider* tires, or larger *diameter* wheels? You could probably fit tires which are 0.5 inches (12.7mm) wider, maybe even more.